# Dailymotion callback url

Tags: callback, key

I am trying to register my app on the dailymotion developers page. I am trying to implement the app on localhost, but when I try to insert 'http: //localhost' (purposely inserted space after http here to be able to write here) on the Dailymotion developer page http://www.dailymotion.com/profile/developer , it just says invalid url. Could someone please tell me what the problem is?

It does allow 127.0.0.1, but it does not seem to work at the moment.

Comment: They're expecting to see your app accessible on the Internet. `localhost` is not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about managing a dailymotion profile.

Comment: They require a publicly accessible URL

Comment: I wanted to test it on localhost first. Youtube allows to do it so. Anyways, thanks for the replies

Comment: Using http://127.0.0.1/yourpage should work

Answer (score 0):

Your app likely needs to be online for it to be used/accessible from dailymotion - even if you wanted your `localhost` network to be accessible via the World Wide Web, that would not be a good idea - localhost is only accessible to you, so you can't use that. You have to upload it on to the internet first

For things like that, I just use Dropbox, and change the share links from:

[`https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbg6xcw3stg0o8b/a.html`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbg6xcw3stg0o8b/a.html)

to:

[`https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tbg6xcw3stg0o8b/a.html`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tbg6xcw3stg0o8b/a.html)

Not ideal it you want it widely used, but it does the job.